# No sound when making outgoing call via JsSIP (Asterisk)

Tags: javascript, asterisk, jssip

I'm trying to debug the existent system, where calls are made via Asteriks.
When accepting incoming calls, everything works fine, but on making outgoing call there is apparently no sound (but I accept 'addstream' event and attach stream to audio). Production code takes 500 lines, but this code does pretty much the same, but doesn't work as well

```
const socket = new JsSIP.WebSocketInterface('wss://callwss.agdevelopments.net');
socket.via_transport = 'wss';
const configuration = {
    password: "SIP4003!",
    realm: "callws,s.agdevelopments.net",
    register: true,
    session_timers: false,
    uri: "sip:4003@callwss.agdevelopments.net",
    sockets: [socket]
}
const ua = new JsSIP.UA(configuration)

//     Setup events
ua.on('connected', function () {
    console.log('Connected')
})
ua.on('disconnected', function () {
    console.log('Connected')
})

//    Make a call

const eventHandlers = {
    'progress': function (e) {
        console.log('call is in progress');
    },
    'failed': function (e) {
        console.log('call failed with cause: ' + (e.data ? e.data.cause : 'no cause'), e);
    },
    'ended': function (e) {
        console.log('call ended with cause: ' + (e.data ? e.data.cause : 'no cause'), e);
    },
    'confirmed': function (e) {
        console.log('call confirmed');
    },
    'addstream': (e) => {
        console.log('Add stream (event handlers)')
        audio.srcObject = e.stream
        audio.play()
    }
};

const options = {
    'eventHandlers': eventHandlers,
    'mediaConstraints': {'audio': true, 'video': false}
};

const audio = new window.Audio()

ua.on('registered', function () {
    const session = ua.call('0513887341', options)

    if (session.connection) {
        console.log('Connection is valid')

        session.connection.addEventListener('addstream', e => {
            console.log('Add stream')
            audio.srcObject = e.stream
            audio.play()
        })

        session.on('addstream', function(e){
            // set remote audio stream (to listen to remote audio)
            // remoteAudio is <audio> element on page
            const remoteAudio = audio
            remoteAudio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(e.stream);
            remoteAudio.play();
        });
        session.connection.addEventListener('peerconnection', e => {
            console.log('Peer connection')
            audio.srcObject = e.stream
            audio.play()
        })
    } else {
        console.log('Connection is null')
    }
})

ua.on('newRTCSession', (data) => {
    console.log('New RTC Session')
    const session = data.session
    session.on('addstream', function(e){
        // set remote audio stream (to listen to remote audio)
        // remoteAudio is <audio> element on page
        const remoteAudio = audio
        remoteAudio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(e.stream);
        remoteAudio.play();
    });

})

ua.start()
```

Also attaching screenshots from Asterisk. The first one is outgoing call with no sound, the second is incoming with sound

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved from IT side. There was no problems in JsSIP or code

Comment: What was the problem and how you have solved it?